# How to notify Main thead from actionEventListner

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, actionlistener

I am creating new object of JFrame in Main Thread and calling its function which call wait(). I want to wake this Main thread.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //some other large code
        var loginWin = new LoginWin();
        loginWin.setVisible(true);
        loginWin.waitForLogin();
        System.out.println("Login Finished");
        //code after login

    }
```

LoginWin extends JFrame and have button which have action Listener like this

```
    login.bsubmit.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
        dataRecived();
    });
```

dataRecived() Function:-

```
private void dataRecived() {

    passwd = login.passwd.getPassword();
    username = login.username.getText();
    iphost = login.iphost.getText();
    port = 9999;
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(login.port.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notify();
}
```

but When I click the login.bsubmit button I get following Exception:-

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at smit.quiz.server.LoginWin.dataRecived(LoginWin.java:52)
    at smit.quiz.server.LoginWin.lambda$new$1(LoginWin.java:34)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: I would consider using `JDialog` over a `JFrame` as it will remove the need for you to do what you're doing. Swing is not thread safe, so it's a bad idea to be trying to interact with the UI elements out side of the context of the EDT.  In order to use `wait`/`notify` you need to be using the same instance of the object AND must be done from within a `synchronized` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is thrown because you invoke [Object.notify()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) without "holding the objects monitor", i.e. from outside of a `synchronized` block or an instance method with the `synchronized` modifier:

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.
>
> Only one thread at a time can own an object's monitor.
>
> Throws:
>     IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of this object's monitor.

---

That said, it is a bad idea to try to modify swing objects from other threads in ways they are not explicitly designed for, see the [swing package docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html):

> **Swing's Threading Policy**
>
> In general Swing is not thread safe. All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented,
>   must be accessed on the event dispatching thread.
>
> [...]
>
> As all events are delivered on the event dispatching thread, care must be taken in event processing. In particular, a long running task, such as network io or computational intensive processing, executed on the event dispatching thread blocks the event dispatching thread from dispatching any other events. While the event dispatching thread is blocked the application is completely unresponsive to user input. Refer to [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for the preferred way to do such processing when working with Swing.
>
> More information on this topic can be found in the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), in particular the section on [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

I would recommend to read these documents, they contain several examples explaining how to implement responsive UIs using swing.